# NameError: 'discord' is not defined?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is for a discord bot I am making, and I have tried to set the bot's status. I've found an answer that looks like `await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="for e/info"))` and I have put it in an `on_ready` event function. However, it gives me the following exception:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", 
    line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\EffeKtive\bot.py", line 14, in on_ready
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="for 
      e/info"))
NameError: name 'discord' is not defined
```

I feel that I am missing an `import`.

Comment: You're going to have to install whatever module is needed to support the code you found. It looks like you need [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py), and then you can do `import discord`.

Comment: I have discord.py already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to `import discord` at the top of your code.

Answer (score 4):

You may have installed discord.py in a seperate location, try installing it to C:\Windows\system32>. You also may be missing an `import`. 
If you are trying to add commands, you also have to: `from discord.ext import commands`.
Is it possible for you to post your code?

Comment: I also dont know if diggy answered your question, it didn't say it had a check by it so I posted this one.